# Why HashSet or HashMap does not support position based accessed? However these class also store object in array of type enter

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I have checked in source code of HashMap at GrepCode.com and found it store object hashcode in array.

```
transient Entry[] table;

  public V put(K key, V value) {
         if (key == null)
             return putForNullKey(value);
         int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
         int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
         for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
             Object k;
             if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
                 V oldValue = e.value;
                 e.value = value;
                 e.recordAccess(this);
                 return oldValue;
             }
         }

         modCount++;
         addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
         return null;
     }

 void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
         Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
         table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
         if (size++ >= threshold)
             resize(2 * table.length);
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Well, position would be based on hashCode function which is neither connected to a sort order nor to insert order which defeats the purpose of an index access.

Comment: Afaik there is no guarantee of any order in a HashSet/HashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is true that internally HashMap/HashSet uses arrays. But neither saving to or retrieval from these arrays are sequential. The reason is simple: these collections use `hashing` to decide the bucket to store and retrieve the objects. Hash calcualted for each entry is not a sequential number. And hash of each element is used to store and retrieve the entries from these collections.

Comment: Can you please give me little-bit hint or source how bucket is identified using hashing? Thanks

Comment: @MdMasoom http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html

Answer (score 4):

This is an internal implementation detail. `HashMap`'s contract makes no guarantee about ordering, so allowing you to have positional access would, in essence, be allowing you to write code that would break every time the implementation is tweaked.

Answer (score 2):

It does indeed 'store object hashcode in an array', but that *doesn't* mean it stores every object in the map in an array. Look again. It stores Entry items in an array, but each Entry item is the head of a linked list. Not every value in the hash table *has* an index into the array. So indexed access would be meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

> Why HashSet or HashMap does not support position based accessed?

- The "position" of an entry in a hash table's array is not stable:

  - If a new entry is added, the positions are liable to change in unpredictable fashion.
  - If you copy a hash table, the positions of elements are liable to change in an unpredictable fashion.
  - The exact behaviour is implementation specific.
- The "position" of an entry in the array is not a complete position, since the array is actual of entry *chains*, not entries.  The complete position of an entry is actually two integers: the hash array index, and the distance from the start of the hash chain.
- The "position" of an entry bears no useful semantic relationship to the entries themselves, or to the order in which they were added.

These things combine to make the "position" practically useless ... and probably dangerous to use.  Hence, it would be a bad idea to support this.

---

<sup>In fact, I over-simplified slightly.  If you know what all of the hash codes are, and the precise sequence of modification operations that was used to get the hash table to its current state, it is possible to figure out the hash chain, and position in the hash chain for each entry.  However, you have to effectively replay the entire sequence of operations to do this.  Besides, even if you did this, you cannot exploit the information to any useful purpose.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The concepts of `Set`s and `Map`s do not include any sort of ordering, so "position-based" access makes no sense. A `Set` either has an element or not, and a `Map` looks up values by keys.  If you want to have some sort of order so that you can select elements by position, use a more-specific data structure like `SortedMap` or `SortedSet`, which keep the elements in sorted order and have elements for partitioning and selecting subranges.

Comment: vote up for specifying what to use if we want position based access to elements

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear way to use a positional index. You have the index of the bucket, but can have multiple entries in a bucket.  This means some positions have no entries, but some have multiple entries.  Whatever strategy you use, there is no way to increment over the indexes in a simple manner.

If you add an entry, all the positions can be re-arranged, making the positions not useful between before and after you add an entry.  Also there is no natural way to express what the index of an entry should be.

The closest option you have is to iterate over the entries and associate an index with each one.  The problem being that it is not efficient or guaranteed to preserved between updates the Map.

Answer (score 0):

[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) does not gaurantee you the order.

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

But if you want, you can go through [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) class, it orders in which the keys were inserted into the map *(insertion-order)*.